# How to evaluate PHP in pattern in node title when I install Automatic Nodetitles module in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I use Automatic Nodetitles module to make node title automatically.However, the title output is:“ Province : Beijing  & nbsp;   City : Beijing   & nbsp; County : Haidian”.
How to remove &nbsp?.

Comment: Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code [you already have](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: title is set :"[node:field_time] [node:author] [node:field_location]".However,  [node:field_location] is an array, and many separator &nbsp; in it.